# Purpose of +xml in HTTP MIME type

Tags: http, mime-types

What's the significance of the `+xml` in the following HTTP Accept Header:

`application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml`

Is that just to denote it's an XML based format, or that it's suitable for XML editors, or something completely different?

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#page-32):

> Appendix A. Why Use the '+xml' Suffix for XML-Based MIME Types?

> Although the use of a suffix was not considered as part of the
> original MIME architecture, this choice is considered to provide the
> most functionality with the least potential for interoperability
> problems or lack of future extensibility.  The alternatives to the
> '+xml' suffix and the reason for its selection are described below.

There is a whole list of reasons listed underneath, but I don't think copying them verbatim falls under fair-use. So check the RFC for their full (long!) story of how this came to be.

Comment: that's pretty definitive, thanks.  Will mark as answer when the timeout expires